# GCC Linker : how to generate a report of per file contribution on output sections

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, statistics, out-of-memory

Recently I meet a problem when trying to link my program. It report `.text` can't fit in specified memory region. Obviously the source code grows too large to be linked in limited memory region.

What I want to do now is to analyze which file contribute most significantly to the ".text" section so that follow up code optimization can be performed. I tried many ways but don't make it.

- `nm -s output.elf` gives size of each symbol, but don't group the symbol under each source file.
- `nm -s file.obj` go through every object file don't work because `-fdata-section` `-ffunction-section` `-Wl` are specified, so not all content in an object file will get linked to final output
- `readelf -s output.elf` gives information from file to file, but it simply list symbols under each file and their size. A script can be written to sum all the size under a file, but the total value seems wrong, an obvious error here is some symbols may point to the same memory location, so the same memory region may be calculated many times.

When gcc link do its work, it should know all the details of what is extracted from a object file and put to the output section, but seems it don't provide a switch to generate a detail report (Or am I missing something?)

Is there any tool which can do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `--gc-sections` together with `--print-gc-sections` and/or `--print-map-discarded`?

If everything is in separate sections, then you have all your sections as input, and list of discarded sections. Then simple script shall produce list of used sections, their size and file mapping.

Comment: Severin, thanks for your suggestion, my toolchain support `--print-gc-sections`, I checked the output and seems it is doable. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Severin, it is done. I iterate through all the object files in my build directory, use `size -A` to collect all section name and size, and using the dictionary built from `ld --print-gc-sections` output, subtract sections that are not linked. It successfully gives nearly every file contribution to the final binary ("Nearly" because there are some standard library not in local build library and are not counted), the result is enough for me to do further work. Thank you for the great help!

Comment: @EricSun Any chance you are sharing your script with us?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, glad to do so. Please see [gist](https://gist.github.com/ericsunplus/1a8068c4a65c9c712a23ec089427701e)