# How to check why some symbol is required for linkage?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang++

This question gets cumbersome, lets try short version:
Usually when you fail with `unresolved symbol reference` it is quite strait forward, here you call something that linker cant find. You just feed your linker with library and it just works. Sometimes, there are cases when you banging your head on the wall and dont see why the linker wants this symbol here and there, it is not called, at least not directly. Is there a tool/linker switch that may explain why it thinks the symbol is needed "here"?

The original question:
It is all about static linkage. I have small utility, couple of lines of code, a couple of includes. The utility linked statically with library named `lib1`. Lets say `lib1` has a dependency on another library, `lib2`, since `lib1` uses symbol `sym1` from `lib2`. However nothing that uses `sym1` from `lib2` is used/called from the utility nor anything from `lib1` that may be dependent on `lib2`. The aforementioned tiny utility however fails with unresolved symbol for `sym1`. The first question is why? Since, in the utility the `sym1` is not required anywhere and even no symbol from `lib1` that uses `sym1` used in the utility, why linker bothers with looking for this symbol in the first place? The second question, there is a chance that inclusion chain introduces the symbol `sym1` to my utility, then it answers the "why" but it should not introduce it (at least there is no obvious reason for that), so the second question is how do I find why linker thinks the utility needs `sym1` from `lib2`?

What/whenre/why: Linux, C/C++, GCC-9/Clang-9

Comment: The reason is because the library is not linked correctly, and it is not linked to the dependent library. As far as "why the linker thinks the utility needs `baz` from `bar`", it seems that you already answered that question, yourself: "`foo` uses the symbol" from that library. You also swapped out `bar` and `baz` in your narrative, a couple of times, which makes it confusing. You should use real symbol names, instead of fake symbol names, to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: lol, will fix it

Comment: rewrote it, like, 5 times and I think it got worse...

Comment: usually it's impossible to answer questions like your first, unless you be specific and give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: How it could be reproducible if I dont understand why it happens?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg See [mcve]. Start removing code from those libraries until the problem disappears (remove irrevelant code first), then add back the last piece of code you removed. What's left will be "reproducible", because it still causes the problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is quite not "Hello World!" application.

Comment: You might have to cut a lot of code to reduce it to one. :) I don't think we'll be able to help without seeing some sort of code.

Comment: Doesn't the gcc linker tell you "referenced from here" when it reports an unresolved symbol?

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure it is, like "src/somesource.cpp:59: error: undefined reference to 'foo::bar::baz() const'". Great. Why? I dont use anything from `somesource.cpp` the object just linked into library I link with, I dont use anything of it, why it needs `foo::bar::baz() const` to be resolved?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg Did you compile lib1 and lib2 with function-section and/or data-section? Do you do sections garbage collection? Along the lines `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fipa-pta main.cpp -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed`

Comment: nope, what these would produce? I definitely can build with these if it would help

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Wow! it linked with no problem! Would you convert your comment to  answer and explain what and why did the trick? Thanks!

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg Done to the best of my abilities

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg You might want to look at another use of gc-sections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869800/gcc-linker-how-to-generate-a-report-of-per-file-contribution-on-output-section/60889238#60889238). Basically, with such script (Eric probably could give it to you) you could get the idea what is used and what is discarded, code size, rodata size etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently I managed to answer the question not seeing the code as well as error message. Time to open my psi-consultancy.

Concerning linking on Linux/ELF target, it is important to remember that linker, while trying to satisfy/resolve symbols, is merging (and copying to final executable) sections (aka segments). Typically app has .text (code segment), .rodata (read-only data) segment, .data (r/w initialized data) segment, .bss (uninitialized data) etc. So if needed symbol is among, say, three functions in one compiled file, whole .text section of the file will be picked. And if unused but present in the section functions calls something else, linker will start searching for that "something else" to satisfy, even if it's irrelevant to the application.

Plus, there is some C++ specific thingy: for class with virtual functions compiler generates vtable, with pointers to each virtual function, and move this table to .rodata section. Note, that what
we think as code is actually ended up in (read-only) DATA section.

If you have all but one virtual functions defined, linker most likely will complain with error message like

```
/tmp/cc5YTcBb.o:(.rodata._ZTV3CL1[_ZTV3CL1]+0x18): undefined reference to `CL1::fnc2()
```

where you could see that problem is with .rodata, not .text.

Moral of the story: chop your code and data into large number of smallest possible sections/segments, your atoms of linking. Ideally, each functions goes into its own section, as well as piece of initialized or r/o data.

Final step is to instruct linker (via -Wl option) to discard (garbage-collect) all unused sections.

In general, one should expect more RAM used by linker, probably slower link stage, but smaller and faster app.

Command line to use, take a look at GCC manual wrt options meaning.

```
g++ -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fipa-pta main.cpp -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed
```